# Disable left clicker once overflow slider has reached a certain point

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Basically I have a carousel slider which I am using to display dates so that a user can scroll across (img below)

[image: Carousel Date slider]

Everything works as it should but my only struggle now is to disable that left button once a user has scrolled so far.. example below

[image: User has clicked left - this should be disabled]

```
<div class="dates-bar">
  <a class="centralprev prev"> <i class="fa fa-angle-left"> </i>
  </a>
  <a data-date="24/07/2016" class="centraldateconed" style="margin-left: 140px;"> <span class="date">24/07</span>  <span class="month">July</span>  <span class="tick"> </span> 
  </a>
  <a data-date="24/07/2016" class="datecon"> <span class="date">31/07</span>  <span class="month">July</span>  <span class="tick"> </span> 
  </a>
  <a data-date="2/08/2016" class="datecon"> <span class="date">02/08</span>  <span class="month">August</span>  <span class="tick"> </span> 
  </a>
  <a data-date="03/08/2016" class="datecon"> <span class="date">03/08</span>  <span class="month">August</span>  <span class="tick"> </span> 
  </a>
  <a data-date="07/08/2016" class="datecon"> <span class="date">07/08</span>  <span class="month">August</span>  <span class="tick"> </span> 
  </a>
  <a class="centralnext next"> <i class="fa fa-angle-right"> </i>
  </a>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Comment: When you click `.centralprev` or `.centralnext` , are you (a)moving the unwanted `<a>`'s out of the visible range of an overflow:hidden `<div class="dates-bar">`, (b) making the unwanted `<a>`'s  `display:none`, (c) removing the unwanted `<a>`'s from their parent element or (d) something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work:
when you click on .centralprev if the number of visible .datecon elements inside .dates-bar is equal to 1 then .centralprev will be hidden, else it will be shown and so will .centralnext:

```
$(".centralprev").click(function(){
if($(".dates-bar>.datecon:visible").length===1){
    $(".centralprev").hide();
    }
else{ 
    $(".centralprev").show();
    $(".centralnext").show();
    }
})
```

And vice versa for the other button:

```
$(".centralnext").click(function(){
if($(".dates-bar>.datecon:visible").length===1){
    $(".centralnext").hide()
    }
else{ 
    $(".centralnext").show();
    $(".centralprev").show();
    }
})
```